# How to change structure .json in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How to change structure .json in Python

From:

```
{ "object": {
        "data_1": "00", 
        "data_2": "00",
        "data_3": "00",
        "data_4": "00",
        "data_5": "00",
        "data_6": "00",
        "data_7": "00",
        "data_8": "00",
        "data_9": "00"
    }
}
```

To:

```
{
        "data_1": "00", 
        "data_2": "00",
        "data_3": "00",
        "data_4": "00",
        "data_5": "00",
        "data_6": "00",
        "data_7": "00",
        "data_8": "00",
        "data_9": "00"
    
}
```

Comment: If data coming from a pandas dataframe you can use DataFrame.to_dict() with several options to format the dict. You can check: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

data = json.loads('{ "object": {"data_1": "00", "data_2": "00","data_3": "00","data_4": "00","data_5": "00","data_6": "00","data_7":"00","data_8": "00","data_9": "00"}}')


data = data["object"]
print(data)
```

all the data you want is the value of `"object"` so just load the data how ever you want and call: `data["object"]`